# Update custom synonyms package version on AWS Elasticsearch domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

We're using AWS's elasticsearch service.  We have a custom synonyms package associated with the elasticsearch domain.  The file lives in an s3 bucket, when the file is updated it triggers a lambda that updates the package version in AWS. We followed the documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/custom-packages.html and so far that all works great for uploading and updating a new version of the package.  However, the way aws elasticsearch custom packages work, each domain that uses the custom package stores its own copy of the file as well. To keep search behavior predictable, domains continue to use their current package version until you explicitly update them.

The problem is that I can't find any way to programmatically tell the domain to use the new version of the package.  It's like 2 clicks in the console, but I cannot for the life of me find a way to do it from my automation code.  The `update_package` method just updates the package version, it doesn't tell the associated domains to use the new version.

We're looking for a way to programatically tell an AWL elasticsearch domain to update the version of an associated custom synonyms file.

Comment: Have you tried the [`_opendistro/_refresh_search_analyzers` API](https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/im/refresh-analyzer/)? (described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/custom-packages.html#custom-packages-updating) in point 6)

Comment: I did - I think that tells the index to use the new version of the package, but still doesn't actually make the new version available on the aws domain.  My understanding here is that when you go to the aws console, select the domain, select the package, and click`update package` it uploads the new version of the package to the domain and then calls `_opendistro/_refresh_search_analyzers`.  It's the first part that I'm struggling with automating.

Answer (score 0):

So after banging my head on this for days and I finally figured it out 5 minutes after posting this question.  You just need to call the `associate_package` method again after you update the package.  I had actually tried that previously and it failed, but it turns out it fails if there is no new version of the package available.  I think I was calling `associate_package` again before the `update_package` method was completed, so the new version wasn't available yet.

Anyway, hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: Yeah I actually opened an issue about this on the AWSSDK java GitHub, since it's not really clear from the documentation what to do. Issue I'm having is that my analyzers don't actually get updated at all... I do see the token filter getting updated, but even calling the '_refresh_search_analyzers' command doesn't;t do anything. Do you experience something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Correct, you have to specifically call associate_package to link to the latest version of that package